# Insert data from API to mysql

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, xml, function

Here I have a code that show restaurants beetween two cities, but there is a problem how to loop objects to insert in database...

http://jsbin.com/AlEVaCa/5

How here I can add my function `loadXMLdoc();`

```
function findPlaces(boxes,searchIndex) {
   var request = {
       bounds: boxes[searchIndex],
       types: ["restaurant"]
   };
   // alert(request.bounds);
   service.radarSearch(request, function (results, status) {
   if (status != google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
     alert("Request["+searchIndex+"] failed: "+status);
     return;
   }
   // alert(results.length);
   document.getElementById('side_bar').innerHTML += "bounds["+searchIndex+"] returns "+results.length+" results<br>"
   for (var i = 0, result; result = results[i]; i++) {
     var marker = createMarker(result);
   }
   searchIndex++;
   if (searchIndex < boxes.length) 
     findPlaces(boxes,searchIndex);
   });
}
```

LoadXMLdoc() :

```
 function loadXMLDoc()
{
   var xmlhttp;
   if (window.XMLHttpRequest){
      // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
      xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
   }
   else{
      // code for IE6, IE5
      xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
   }

   xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
     if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
     {
        document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
     }
   }

   data = "name="+place.name+"&place="+place.website;
   xmlhttp.open("POST","file_to_store.php",true);
   xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
   xmlhttp.send(data);
}
    });
```

so How to integrate my function loadXMLdoc for script to insert data to database?

Comment: Why did you write your own [jQuery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) function?

Comment: ? to post data to mysql database...

Comment: I mean why did you write your own rather than just use the jQuery one?

Comment: I dont know how ? please show me on my example